# how to forward from port 80 to 8080 using iptables without opening port 8080?

Tags: linux, iptables

The following iptables configuration work for forwarding port 80 to 8080.

```
#nat chains

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i bond1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
-A PREROUTING -i bond1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443 
COMMIT

#filter chains 

*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

However in this setup a user can send a request to port 80 and to port 8080 because of

```
 -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Is there a way to define the ip table rules so that port 80 forwards to port 8080 but port 8080 is not exposed to the outside world?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my nat prerouting table to redirect packets to port 8080 and 8443 on the external nic to port 77 where the input filter chain will drop them. I am not really sure if this is the best way to do things but it works.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -i bond1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
-A PREROUTING -i bond1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443 

#Redirect port 8080,8843 to a port that is blocked this way will appear closed  
-A PREROUTING -i bond1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 77 
-A PREROUTING -i bond1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 77 

COMMIT
```