# IPtables rule to double NAT

Tags: iptables, firewall, filter, nat

Let me rephrase it.. I just need an IPtable rule to do double NAT-ting..

```
Host A - Host B - Host C - Host D
```

Host B should do both source NAT and destination NAT, so that my request from Host A reaches Host C and response from Host C reaches Host A.

In the same way, Host C should take care of requests from Host B to Host D and vice-versa.

So, basically, at end of the day, I want a request from Host A to Host D to happen, and a response from Host D to Host A to happen.

I am a little confused with where we need to use PREROUTING, POSTROUTING..

Comment: Would a web proxy be acceptable in your case ? It's more usual to do that this way.

Comment: I'm not able to test right now so I won't post this as an answer but I would try :
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp –dport 443 -j DNAT –to-destination 127.0.0.1:7777`

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp –dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double port forwarding - SSH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117252/double-port-forwarding-ssh)

Comment: @Kiwy For me, it's a new question. It's entirely different to make a double port forwarding with SSH tunnels and making an iptables rule for a port redirection within a single host.

Comment: then he could have edit his other question or remove it because the final goal is excatly the same and the OP does not event answer the comments made in the first question

Comment: For me, it's more a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114139/how-to-forward-from-port-80-to-8080-using-iptables-without-opening-port-8080.

Comment: Could you tell us the relevant rules how they are writen?

Comment: You write "Only HOST C can access HOST B". If only host C can access Host B as you are writing, how can **ever** forward a port from host A to host B as host A cannot access B. And if that all is not true, you should simplefy your question (and e.g. leave host A out of it completely

Comment: Mmm... if I'm not mistaken you don't need to change anything relevant, just doing nat.